# Why is the harmonic mean called the "subcontrary mean"?

Tags: logic, terminology, definition, math-history

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) and Eric W. Weisstein's wonderful [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubcontraryMean.html), a synonym for "harmonic mean" (n.) is "subcontrary mean" (n.). This is an interesting terminology because it evokes the image of the square of opposition:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\textrm{All S are P} @>{\textrm{contrary}}>> \textrm{No S is P}\\
@V{\textrm{subalterm}}VV @V{\textrm{subalterm}}VV\\
\textrm{Some S are P} @>{\textrm{subcontrary}}>> \textrm{Some S are not P}
\end{CD}

(note: due to the limitations of the `AMScd` package the case of contradiction could not be represented.)

What is the reason behind naming the harmonic mean the subcontrary mean?

Comment: This might be a good question for hsm.se.

Comment: See [Tripod : Harmonic mean](http://jeff560.tripod.com/h.html): "A surviving fragment of the work of Archytas of Tarentum (ca. 350 BC) states, 'There are three means in music: one is the arithmetic, the second is the geometric, and the third is the subcontrary, which they call harmonic.' The term harmonic mean was also used by Aristotle. According to one theory, the term *subcontrary* may refer to the fact that a tone based on this mean reverses the order of the two fundamental musical intervals in a scale."